# Should we use localized tags

Tags: internationalisation, tags, tagging

I am creating a webpage in which I have a form to register new products. I have implemented tagging feature (metatags to allow searching my products in search engines).

I am allowing users to register products in different languages.

Should I also use tags in different languages? Is it recommended to use tags in multiple languages?

Comment: I'd translate them for display, and store them in one language.

Comment: It is up You and the design of your webpage I guess.

Comment: Is your webpage already online and are your users asking for this feature? Is the tagging a core feature of your website and do you plan to several languages represented among the users? Are you creating the website and are you interested in tag translation? Unless you answered yes to one of this question, you probably have features more important that you should focus on.

Comment: I am using these tags as `metatags` later for corresponding details.

Comment: You need to provide much more details ("tagging feature" and "form" can mean many things). And as this doesn’t seem to be about implementation, it should probably be migrated to [ux.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some reasons why it's ideal to translate your tags or categorizations:

- Tag labels presented to users won't be understandable in another language. If your company is a German rail equipment manufacturer, you shouldn't expect an American to understand "Straßenbahnsignalsystem", nor should an American manufacturer expect others to understand "Light rail signaling system".
- Tag "slugs" or URI segments (e.g. /news/category/health) should be translated for better SEO performance, helping your users find your content (e.g. /nouvelles/categorie/sante in French).

Note that you may not need to map tags one-to-one between your languages or locales. If your tags are specific to a market it may not make sense to have them in another market.

Another thought... Having parts of your interface untranslated may create a jarring experience for your user. If you're not in the position to tag in all of your different locales, consider only tagging those where you can. It might make more sense to not offer a functionality than to create a confusing or frustrating experience.